# Getting String Value From Database in C#

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, n-tier-architecture

I have a database table in which i am saving created users along with username now what i want to get string value from my database if username exists in database and then i will show error message "UserName Exists or Choose new one etc etc"

here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_SaveUpdate_AdminUserAccount]

 (    
 @Id_User int,    
 @nm_UserName varchar(50),      
 @nm_UserPassword varchar(50),      
 @nm_UserRole int      
 )    
AS    
BEGIN    
IF @Id_User=0    
 BEGIN 
 Declare @count int
    Select @count=COUNT(1) from ref_Admin_UserAccount where nm_UserName=@nm_UserName
    if(@count > 0)
    begin
        select -1 as a;
    end
    else
    BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  Insert into ref_Admin_UserAccount(nm_UserName,nm_UserPassword,nm_UserRole)  

values(@nm_UserName,@nm_UserPassword,@nm_UserRole) 
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
end

END    
ELSE    
 BEGIN    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;    
  UPDATE ref_Admin_UserAccount    
   SET    
   nm_UserName=@nm_UserName,    
   nm_UserPassword=@nm_UserPassword,    
   nm_UserRole=@nm_UserRole   
  WHERE Id_User=@Id_User;    
  SELECT @Id_User;    
End    
End
```

and here is my code to save values in database from presentation layer using 3 tier archiecture

```
 public int SaveAdminUserAccountInformation(AdminAccountProperties oAdminUser)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] parm = new SqlParameter[4];

                parm[0] = new SqlParameter(PARM_ADMIN_USER_ID, SqlDbType.Int);
                parm[0].Value = oAdminUser.UserID;
                parm[1] = new SqlParameter(PARM_USER_NAME, SqlDbType.VarChar);
                parm[1].Value = oAdminUser.UserName;
                parm[2] = new SqlParameter(PARM_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD, SqlDbType.VarChar);
                parm[2].Value = oAdminUser.Password;
                parm[3] = new SqlParameter(PARM_USER_ROLE, SqlDbType.Int);
                parm[3].Value = oAdminUser.UserRole;
                return Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(this._ConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SQL_ADMIN_USER_INSERT_UPDATE, parm));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
        }
```

please give me some help.

Comment: use SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)

Comment: where to use it in stored procedure?\

Comment: why not to return int value because in your stored procedure you are getting -1 if username exists...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure returns -1 if username exists so i suggest you to return int rather than string in your Data Access Layer.
here is some modifications in your code

```
 public int SaveAdminUserAccountInformation(AdminAccountProperties oAdminUser)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] parm = new SqlParameter[4];

                parm[0] = new SqlParameter(PARM_ADMIN_USER_ID, SqlDbType.Int);
                parm[0].Value = oAdminUser.UserID;
                parm[1] = new SqlParameter(PARM_USER_NAME, SqlDbType.VarChar);
                parm[1].Value = oAdminUser.UserName;
                parm[2] = new SqlParameter(PARM_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD, SqlDbType.VarChar);
                parm[2].Value = oAdminUser.Password;
                parm[3] = new SqlParameter(PARM_USER_ROLE, SqlDbType.Int);
                parm[3].Value = oAdminUser.UserRole;
                int a =Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(this._ConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SQL_ADMIN_USER_INSERT_UPDATE, parm));
return a;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
        }
```

after this on basis of return value do what ever you want to do in presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead Selecting the New row in Stored Procedure. Use an OUT Parameter of the Stored Procedure. Like the Code Below :

```
                try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "USP_IUD_FAC_SUBJECT";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EVENT", EVENTI);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FAC_SUB_CODE", FAC_SUB_CODE);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FAC_SUB_NAME", FAC_SUB_NAME);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRAN_DATE", TRAN_DATE);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRAN_USER_ID", TRAN_USER_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APPROVED", APPROVED);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APPROVED_DATE", APPROVED_DATE);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APPROVED_USER_ID", APPROVED_USER_ID);

                SqlParameter outparameter = new SqlParameter("@MSG", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
                outparameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(outparameter);

                SqlParameter OutId = new SqlParameter("@RETURNOUTID", SqlDbType.Int);
                OutId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(OutId);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                object msg = cmd.Parameters[outparameter.ParameterName].Value;
                ReturnId2 = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters[OutId.ParameterName].Value);

                return Convert.ToString(msg);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                transaction.Commit();
                DL_CCommon.Connection().Close();
            }
```

So, Create the Stored Procedure with an Out Parameter. And, Set the Required value into that Out parameter in Procedure. For using Out Parameter in Stored Procedure Follow the link :  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-to-write-a-Stored-procedure-in-Sql

Answer (score 0):

### SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_SaveUpdate_AdminUserAccount]
  @Id_User int,    
 @nm_UserName varchar(50),      
 @nm_UserPassword varchar(50),      
 @nm_UserRole int,  
 @id int OUTPUT
AS
```

### C#

```
SqlConnection db = DataConn.SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(
           "p_SaveUpdate_AdminUserAccount @Id_User, @nm_UserName, @nm_UserPassword, @nm_UserRole, @id", db, transaction) { CommandType = CommandType.Text };
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id_User", SqlDbType.Int)).Value;
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nm_UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value;
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nm_UserPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value;
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nm_UserRole", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value;
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

sqlComm.Parameters.Add(param);
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```